# javafx: keep oldValue and newValue of listview the same when condition has not been fullfilled

Tags: java, javafx

I've got a listview where I can select different panes that will show up in the main pane. Now for a particular pane I need some objects to use every function. On the listview there is a listener on the selectedItemProperty. I want to check if the objects I need are available, otherwise the objects oldValue and newValue should keep their value. Is there a way of doing that?

```
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object> observable, Object oldValue,
                            Object newValue)
    {
        if(obj == null)
        {
            // keep the oldValues for both
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a runnable example in the first code snippet the second snippet is what it would look like in your program

```
public class MainNoFXML extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<Object> listView = new ListView<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(new String[]{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday"}));
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal)->{
            if(newVal != null && (!newVal.equals("Monday") && !newVal.equals("Tuesday")))
                Platform.runLater(() -> listView.getSelectionModel().select(oldVal));
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(listView);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Your Program(I think this is correct not exactly sure what your working with)

```
listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Object> observable, Object oldValue,
                            Object newValue)
        {
            if(obj == null)
            {
                Platform.runLater(() -> listView.getSelectionModel().select(oldValue));
                // keep the oldValues for both
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use a custom selection model to prevent some items from being selected.

The following implementation is simplified. It doesn't handle changes of the item list. Furthermore it implements single selection only, but hopefully it shows the general approach:

```
public class CustomSelectionModel<T> extends MultipleSelectionModel<T> {

    private final ListView<T> listView;
    private final ObservableList<Integer> selectedIndices = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private final ObservableList<Integer> selectedIndicesUnmodifiable = FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(selectedIndices);
    private final ObservableList<T> selectedItems;

    private BiPredicate<Integer, T> leavePredicate;
    private BiPredicate<Integer, T> enterPredicate;

    public BiPredicate<Integer, T> getLeavePredicate() {
        return leavePredicate;
    }

    public void setLeavePredicate(BiPredicate<Integer, T> leavePredicate) {
        this.leavePredicate = leavePredicate;
    }

    public BiPredicate<Integer, T> getEnterPredicate() {
        return enterPredicate;
    }

    public void setEnterPredicate(BiPredicate<Integer, T> enterPredicate) {
        this.enterPredicate = enterPredicate;
    }

    public CustomSelectionModel(ListView<T> listView) {
        if (listView == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.listView = listView;
        this.selectedItems = new TransformationList<T, Integer>(selectedIndices) {

            @Override
            protected void sourceChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer> c) {
                beginChange();
                while (c.next()) {
                    if (c.wasReplaced()) {
                        nextReplace(c.getFrom(), c.getTo(), c.getRemoved().stream().map(listView.getItems()::get).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    } else if (c.wasRemoved()) {
                        nextRemove(c.getFrom(), c.getRemoved().stream().map(listView.getItems()::get).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    } else if (c.wasAdded()) {
                        nextAdd(c.getFrom(), c.getTo());
                    }
                }
                endChange();
            }

            @Override
            public int getSourceIndex(int index) {
                return index;
            }

            @Override
            public T get(int index) {
                return listView.getItems().get(getSource().get(index));
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                return getSource().size();
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<Integer> getSelectedIndices() {
        return selectedIndicesUnmodifiable;
    }

    @Override
    public ObservableList<T> getSelectedItems() {
        return selectedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public void selectIndices(int index, int... indices) {
        clearAndSelect(index); // ignore all indices but the first
    }

    @Override
    public void selectAll() {
        selectFirst();
    }

    @Override
    public void selectFirst() {
        if (!listView.getItems().isEmpty()) {
            clearAndSelect(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectLast() {
        if (!listView.getItems().isEmpty()) {
            clearAndSelect(listView.getItems().size() - 1);
        }
    }

    private void moveSelection(int oldIndex, int newIndex) {
        if ((leavePredicate == null || leavePredicate.test(oldIndex, oldIndex == -1 ? null : listView.getItems().get(oldIndex)))
                && (enterPredicate == null || enterPredicate.test(newIndex, newIndex == -1 ? null : listView.getItems().get(newIndex)))) {
            setSelectedIndex(newIndex);
            if (newIndex == -1) {
                selectedItems.clear();
                setSelectedItem(null);
            } else {
                setSelectedItem(listView.getItems().get(newIndex));
                if (isEmpty()) {
                    selectedIndices.add(newIndex);
                } else {
                    selectedIndices.set(0, newIndex);
                }
            }
            listView.getFocusModel().focus(newIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearAndSelect(int index) {
        moveSelection(getSelectedIndex(), index);
    }

    @Override
    public void select(int index) {
        clearAndSelect(index);
    }

    @Override
    public void select(T obj) {
        int index = listView.getItems().indexOf(obj);
        if (index >= 0) {
            clearAndSelect(index);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection(int index) {
        if (getSelectedIndex() == index) {
            clearSelection();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearSelection() {
        moveSelection(getSelectedIndex(), -1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int index) {
        return selectedIndices.contains(index);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return selectedIndices.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void selectPrevious() {
        int index = getSelectedIndex() - 1;
        if (index >= 0) {
            clearAndSelect(index);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void selectNext() {
        int index = getSelectedIndex() + 1;
        if (index < listView.getItems().size()) {
            clearAndSelect(index);
        }
    }

}
```

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ListView<Integer> listView = new ListView<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        listView.getItems().add(i);
    }

    CustomSelectionModel<Integer> selectionModel = new CustomSelectionModel<>(listView);
    listView.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);

    CheckBox moveAllowed = new CheckBox("disallow movement");
    moveAllowed.selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> selectionModel.setLeavePredicate(newValue ? (index, item) -> false : null));

    CheckBox enterOdd = new CheckBox("enter odd items disallowed");
    enterOdd.selectedProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> selectionModel.setEnterPredicate(newValue ? (index, item) -> (index & 1) == 0 : null));

    Scene scene = new Scene(new ScrollPane(new HBox(listView, new VBox(moveAllowed, enterOdd))));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```